# ASUS ZenScreen MB16AC Portable USB Monitor stopped working

Tags: dell-xps

I have been using the ASUS ZenScreen MB16AC Portable USB Monitor with a Dell XPS 13" laptop with USB C cable on Windows 10 64 bit. Suddenly the monitor stopped working and it doesn´t turn on anymore. I took it to the shop and it worked there with the same usb c cable but another computer. Any ideas what I could try?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was not enough to just restart my laptop, I had to do a complete **shutdown** and when turning back on everything worked again. Also make sure to update all drivers for the laptop as well as the screen. Just to add not all usb ports on the laptop where charging ports.